# empty value from stream_context_create()

Tags: php, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have used for adaptive paypal payment. Use this Code

```
$params = array("http" => array( 
    "method" => "POST",
    "content" => $body_data,
    "header" =>  "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: " . $API_UserName . "\r\n" .
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: " . $API_Signature . "\r\n" .
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: " . $API_Password . "\r\n" .
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: " . $API_AppID . "\r\n" .
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_RequestFormat . "\r\n" .
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_ResponseFormat . "\r\n" 
));

$ctx = stream_context_create($params);

//open the stream and send request
$fp = @fopen($url, "r", false, $ctx);

//get response
$response = stream_get_contents($fp);

//check to see if stream is open
if ($response === false) {
   throw new Exception("php error message = " . "$php_errormsg");
}

//close the stream
fclose($fp);
```

but it display error message

> Message: ||php error message = stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given||

How to Remove this please Help me... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because:

```
$fp = @fopen($url, "r", false, $ctx);
```

is returning a FALSE boolean value. Remove the @ operator ([error control](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)) and see if your function is throwing any errors or notices. Also, check and make sure that your URL is correct.

Comment: i have remove that @ symbol but it display this two error messages    1)  fopen(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? 2)fopen(https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay): failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Comment: 1) fopen(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? 2)fopen(svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay): failed to open stream: Invalid argument –

Answer (score 0):

Your `fopen()` call has failed (returned false). Why are you suppressing errors on that with the `@`?

Whatever is in `$url` could not be accessed. Check the resource is accessible and there are no networking problems.

If you are trying to access a `https` secured link then you will need OpenSSL installed and enabled.

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.